# How to list the applications that have read or write access to your Google account using the Google API?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-api, google-workspace, google-workspace-add-ons

I'm seeking help listing an application (third party) that has read/write permissions to my Google account. I tried reading the Google workspace SDK API documentation but found no helpful method.

I would highly appreciate anyone who can help me implement this in Python.

I tried to find any relevant method in the Google SDK API, but it didn't help. I'm expecting documentation resources or anything similar from someone who has worked on something similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no api that will show you who has access to your google account.  The only way to see this is to check the the security tab in your google account manually.

[Apps with access to your account](https://myaccount.google.com/permissions?continue=https%3A%2F%2Fmyaccount.google.com%2Fdata-and-privacy)

Comment: Adding to this answer, you can create a Feature Request on Google Issue Tracker. This is the [Admin SDK template link](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=191635&template=824102)

Comment: What if I'm a workspace admin and want to list the apps/services that have read/write access to my workspace accounts (users)?

Comment: Okay okay in that case try [activities/list](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/reference/rest/v1/activities/list)